# Using http.createServer in electron renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm using a simple electron react boilerplate from here:
https://github.com/shekhargulati/electron-react-quick-start

The boilerplate is left as-is except for `renderer.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create simple http server
    const http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('Hello World!');
      res.end();
    }).listen(8080);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <h1>Minimalistic Electron React Boilerplate Code :)</h1>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

I get the following error:
`TypeError: http.createServer is not a function`

Is `http.createServer` not usable in a renderer process?